# Riemann-Stieltjes Integral with respect to a non-monotonic discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I need to determine the existence of the following Riemann-Stieltjes
integral, and calculate it if it exists.

$
\int_{0}^{2}xd(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)
$

Where
$
\lfloor x\rfloor=\max\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:n\leq x\}
$

So basically what I'm asking is how to determine the existence of
the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of a continuous function with respect
to a non-monotonic integrator with a discontinuity.

The definition of R-S integrability that I'm using is the following:

$f\in\mathrm{R}(\alpha)$ if $\exists A\varepsilon\mathbb{R}/\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists P_{\varepsilon}$  such
that $P\supseteq P_{\epsilon}$ implies $|S(f,P,\alpha)-A|<\epsilon$
$\forall t_{1},\dots,t_{n}$ where

$P=[a=x_{0},x_{1},\dots,x_{n-1},x_{n}=b]$ and
[$
S(f,P,\alpha)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(t_{k})[\alpha(x_{k})-\alpha(x_{k-1})]
$ with $t_{k}\in[x_{k},x_{k-1}]$

If it exists, we say $A=\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha$